# I wanted to access .so lib and methods of it's cpp files from Android studio

Tags: java, android, c++, android-gradle-plugin, java-native-interface

I wanted to access .so lib file and methods of it's cpp files from Android studio.

> Code in Android studio => In JAVA Code in .so lib => In CPP Code of
>   JNI => In CPP

.so lib file will be access from JNI and from JNI to JAVA.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Yes, JNI is the right tool for this. Now, do you have an actionable question we can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a wrapper for that shared library with the JNI/NDK and then you are able to call your JNI/NDK implementation in Kotlin or Java.

To load your c/c++ it in Java:

```
System.loadLibrary("lib-wrapper");
```

To create an interface in Java:

```
package my.package.name;
class LibWrapper {
  /**
   * Native method implemented in C/C++
   */
  public native String wrapperFunction();

}
```

and then in your in your lib-wrapper.c

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_my_package_name_LibWrapper_wrapperFunction( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz ) {
   // call your .so code here
   // then return your result
   return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "wrapperFunction Result");
}
```

More resources:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni#java

Comment: Your question is not clear. This page will help you. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code